# What are the (real) coefficients $a (t), b (t)$ of the representation $r (t)$?

Tags: analysis

A spaceship flies in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$ with constant speed in the direction of the x-axis.

Physicist P1 uses the canonical unit vectors $e_1 = (1, 0) = 1$ and $e_2 = (0, 1) = i$ as the coordinate system; in this the location of the spaceship at time $t$ is given by $r (t) = (t, 0) = t$.

Physicist P2 uses a coordinate system rotating around $0$, whose (time-dependent) Axes he holds for the guidelines of the universe, and that are given by
$\tilde{e}_1 (t) = (\cos (t), \sin (t)) = \cos (t) + i\sin (t)$, $\tilde{e}_2 (t) = (- \sin (t), \cos (t)) = - \sin (t) + i \cos (t)$

What are the (real) coefficients $a (t), b (t)$ of the representation $r (t) =
a (t) \tilde{e}_1 (t) + b (t) \tilde{e}_2 (t)$ in the system of P2 explicit?

$$$$

From $r (t) =a (t) \tilde{e}_1 (t) + b (t) \tilde{e}_2 (t)$ we get $(t,0)=a (t) (\cos (t), \sin (t)) + b (t) (- \sin (t), \cos (t)) $.

So we have to solve the system $$t=a(t)\cos t-b(t)\sin t \\ 0 =a(t)\sin t+b(t)\cos t$$ or not? Do we have to differentiate these equations?

Do we use also that the speed is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Fix $t$.  For a given orthonormal basis $\{\tilde{e}_1 (t),\tilde{e}_2 (t)\}$, find the coordinates for a given vector $r(t)$ with respect to that basis using inner products:

$$
a(t) = r(t) \cdot \tilde{e}_1 (t),\\
b(t) = r(t) \cdot \tilde{e}_2 (t) .
$$

---

Yes, we are solving the system you wrote.  But the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is easy!

Comment: So you mean to write the system in matrix form?

Comment: So we have $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & -\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a(t) \\ b(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}a(t) \\ b(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & -\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}t \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ Or did you mean something else?

Comment: For a fixed $t$ we get $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & -\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & \sin t \\ -\sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & \sin t \\ -\sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}$ and so we get $$\begin{pmatrix}a(t) \\ b(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t & \sin t \\ -\sin t & \cos t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t\cos t \\ -t\sin t  \end{pmatrix}$$ right?

Comment: You can think of it that way.  But alternately, since $\{\tilde{e}_1 (t) ,\tilde{e}_2 (t)\}$ is an orthonormal basis, the inner product $(a (t) \tilde{e}_1 (t) + b (t) \tilde{e}_2 (t))\cdot  \tilde{e}_1 (t)$ is $a(t)$.  If you think you have an answer, you can plug it in and see if it works, you don't need to ask me.

Comment: Is this an orthonormal basis because $\tilde{e}_i\cdot \tilde{e}_j=0$ and $\tilde{e}_i\cdot \tilde{e}_i=1$ with $i\neq j$ ?

Comment: Correct.  More generally, rotating a known orthonormal basis yields another orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :-)